# Apps running on Windows Containers are available only in Hyper-V Container enabled SKU

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-devops, containers

I want to publish the asp.net core project on Azure. I've created a container and pushed it on the docker repository. next, I created a web app on Azure. but whenever I select publish operating system as a 'Windows', I got the below error  :

```
Apps running on Windows Containers are available only in Hyper-V Container enabled SKU.
```

I'm using a free trial subscription to the Azure account.

Answer (score 2):

Apps on Windows containers is a web apps for containers feature that is supported only on Premium V3 App service. Which app service plan are you on?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

As the error message indicates, you need a Hyper-v enabled App Service Plan SKU and Premium V3 app service plans are Hyper-V enabled

Comment: Thanks Hari, I'm deploying .net core project

Comment: Ok. Still doesn’t change the fact that Windows containers need Preimum SKU